# Evidence for indistinguishable particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, identical-particles, exchange-interaction

What's the simplest evidence for indistinguishable particles?  Is there any evidence/experiment without resorting to large ensemble/statistical results?

Comment: Would [HOM effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect) count?

Comment: Finding a [magnetic monopole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole) would be a step in the right direction. It would explain why all electrons have the same charge. Searches have been carried out, but none have been found so far.

Comment: @PM2Ring the article is worth it but thanks for bringing out that issue, I will remove the comment we might remove ours too...

Comment: @Mauricio I transformed your comment (which I had already upvoted) into the answer below.  HOM is indeed the best example, and the effect clearly does not involve large ensemble.

Comment: See the papers and experiments discussed in this talk after 24 min 40s timestamp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqxMoBC--lo&t=1545s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A spectacular example is provided by the [Hong-Ou-Mandel experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect):

> Hong, Chong-Ki, Zhe-Yu Ou, and Leonard Mandel. "Measurement of subpicosecond time intervals between two photons by interference." *Physical Review Letters* 59.18 (1987): 2044.

In this experiment, partially overlapping pulses are sent through different input ports of a 50/50 interferometer.  The degree of (partial) distinguishability is controlled by the time delay between the pulses.

[image]

(Picture credit: Brańczyk, Agata M, see below).

In particular, when the two pulses exactly overlap, the photon pulses are exactly indistinguishable, leading to totally destructive interference (for 50-50 beam splitters) and a resulting dip in the number of photons counted in *different* detectors at the output ports.  Here's [a video illustrating the effect in this case.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld2r2IMt4vg&ab_channel=QuantumLightUniversityofSheffield) Below is a graphical illustration of the situation, where the shaded detection scenarios are absent for exactly indistinguishable particles.

[image]

For fully indistinguishable particles, the coincidence count shows a characteristic dip (for bosons). For partially indistinguishable particles, the count rate in *different* detectors slowly rises with increasing distinguishability.  In the experimental results of Hong, Ou and Mandel:

[image]

the shape of the curve (an inverse Gaussian in this case) is determined by the actual shape of the pulses and details about the detection processes.  The dip doesn't exactly reach $0$ because the pulses are experimentally not exactly of the same shape so the destructing interference is not perfect at the maximum overlap of the pulses.

Various pulse shapes and detection scenarios, as well as a good pedagogical discussion of HOM interference, can be found in

> Agata M Brańczyk, "Hong-Ou-Mandel interference." [arXiv preprint arXiv:1711.00080 (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00080)

Answer (score 2):

[*Exchange interaction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_interaction) is often used as a term for the effects that arise due to the indistinguishability of particles. Notably, the stability of electron gas in metals can be explained only by taking into account the indistinguishability of electrons - otherwise the electrons metal should spread outside like a gas. Similar effects can be studied for other materials - perhaps, somebody with relevant expertise could comment on the importance of exchange for stability of the nuclei and the existence of the Universe as we know it.

In other words, the evidence is all around us.

Comment: The gas of electrons in a metal is maybe a large ensemble for OP. However scattering experiment results between electrons clearly depend on this exchange interaction.

Comment: @Mauricio I agree. On the other hand, one can easily convince oneself that electrons do not evaporate from a piece of metal, making it positively charged.

Comment: I find your answer clear enough but I think it just addresses the title.

Comment: @Mauricio You have a point here.

Comment: @RogerV. if electrons in a metal were distinguishable, they would evaporate away? Please explain why.

Comment: @Prem if one ignores Fock term in Hartree-Fock, the electrons evaporate.

Answer (score 0):

Physics theories have developed since Newton's time as mathematical models that fit the data and observations, and, important, are predictive of data and observations within experimental errors.

The mathematics used in the model are a different discipline, axiomatic, and can have innumerable solutions and equations that predict science fiction states. To pick up the solutions and equations which can model and predict data new statements with the strength of axioms are used. They are called postulates ([quantum mechanics)](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=hyperphysics%20quantum%20nechanics%20postulates.), principles, and some are implicit in the definitions of the model.

In the standard model of physics one of these axiomatic implications is that the particles [in the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle)  , at rest , would be indistinguishable.  This comes from the mathematical tool of Feynman diagrams where this axiomatic assumption is basic in guiding the calculations . As is well known the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) is very successful in modeling the particle data . Thus it is the bulk of experimental data that support the axiomatic statement that elementary particles are indistinguishable.

As particle physics experiments are  continually looking for disagreements with the standard model in order to explore new physics, it is possible that in the future a small effect might be found. IMO it is improbable that we should be able to label elementary particles by particular names.